# git repo in a git repo? (non submodule)

Tags: git

```
.git // <-- pushed to bitbucket
  |- gulpfile.js // <-- process src files to dist files
  |- ...(more files)
  |- src
      |- ...(more files)
  |- dist
      |- .git // <-- pushed to server
      |- ...(more files)
```

Anyway for a git repo to include another git repo in it? I have a development structure which uses gulp to process it to a dist directory, in that directory sits a git repo which I am able to push to my server.

I know that submodule exists however that requires me to upload the dist .git to a remote repo. I do not need a centralized repo for this one, it feels like overkill, I just need to upload the files to the server in different versions.

So is this possible? If not how do developers tackle this workflow I am using?

Comment: Why do you "have to upload the dist .git to a remote repo" with submodules?

Comment: @martin It doesn't mention of local of what I read! I'll go read about local repos.

Comment: I have not tried that thoroughly, but if you have a backup: Add the local as submodul with local path and try `git submodule init`, `git submodule sync`, etc, to see if it breaks, it didn't break for me iirc, but I won't say that in an answer :).

Comment: I don't understand either why you say "requires me to upload the dist .git to a remote repo" when your example explicitly says that you push to a server.

Comment: Do you need to keep track of which commit of the subrepo corresponds to which commit of the superrepo? If not, then just put `/dist` in your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submodule was indeed the answer. It was however tricky to setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to use submodule, you can set one git repo as a compressed package to avoid git conflict，but there should be a better method.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer. Could you elaborate?